# Proving L1 ∪ L2 ⊆ L1* L2*

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages

I'm stuck here, how can i prove this:
$$L_1 \cup L_2 \subseteq L_1^*L_2^*$$

$$\begin{array}{rcl}
x\in L_1\cup L_2 & \Rightarrow & x\in L_1^* \lor x\in L_2^*\\
&\Rightarrow &x\in L_1^*\cup L_2^*
\end{array}$$

What's next?

Answer (score 1):

Star closure of $L_1$ is
$$L_1^*=L_1^0 \cup L_1^1\cup L_1^3\cup\dots\;\;.$$
Also star closure of $L_2$ is as follow
$$L_2^*=L_2^0\cup L_2^1\cup L_2^2\cup L_2^3\dots\;\;.$$
Obviously, concatenation  of
$$ L_1^*L_2^*=\{L_1^0 \cup L_1^1\cup L_1^3\cup\dots\}\{L_2^0\cup L_2^1\cup L_2^2\cup L_2^3\dots \} $$
has languages like
$$L_1\cup L_2$$ as its subset.

Answer (score 0):

You can show first that $L_1 \cup L_2 \subset L_1^*L_2^*$:

- Note that $L_1^*L_2^* = L_1^0L_2^* \cup L_1^1L_2^* \cup L_1^2L_2^* \cup ... $. Since $\varepsilon \in L^*$ and $L=L^1$, it follows that $L_1 \subset L_1^1L_2^*$ which then implies that $L_1 \subset L_1^*L_2^*$.
- To show that $L_2 \subset L_1^*L_2^*$ use the same idea as above but using the fact that $L_1^*L_2^* = L_1^*L_2^0 \cup L_1^*L_2^1 \cup L_1^*L_2^2 \cup...$.

Now, if $L_1$ and $L_2$ are both $\{\varepsilon\} $ then $L_1 \cup L_2 = L_1^*L_2^*$, since $\varepsilon^*=\varepsilon$ and $\varepsilon\varepsilon =\varepsilon$.

Using all those facts above, $L_1 \cup L_2 \subseteq L_1^*L_2^*$.

Answer (score 0):

L1* L2* contains among many others any string in L1 concatenated with 0 strings from L2, and 0 strings from L1 concatenated with any string of L2. That’s it.